# Вменяемый конвертер времени в команде mute. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нужен вменяемый конвертер времени. Чтобы при написании команды *mute {reason} {time} в значении time можно было указать к примеру 30h или 30m и команда блокировала доступ не на 30 секунд, а 30 минут. Использую asyncio.sleep

Comment: И что у вас не получается? Распарсите строку на цифры и буквы.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю вам подойдёт эта функция:

```
def str_time_to_seconds(str_time, language):
    conv_dict = {
        'w': 'weeks',
        'week': 'weeks',
        'weeks': 'weeks',
        'н': 'weeks',
        'нед': 'weeks',
        'неделя': 'weeks',
        'недели': 'weeks',
        'недель': 'weeks',
        'неделю': 'weeks',

        'd': 'days',
        'day': 'days',
        'days': 'days',
        'д': 'days',
        'день': 'days',
        'дня': 'days',
        'дней': 'days',

        'h': 'hours',
        'h': 'hours',
        'hour': 'hours',
        'hours': 'hours',
        'ч': 'hours',
        'час': 'hours',
        'часа': 'hours',
        'часов': 'hours',

        'm': 'minutes',
        'min': 'minutes',
        'mins': 'minutes',
        'minute': 'minutes',
        'minutes': 'minutes',
        'мин': 'minutes',
        'минута': 'minutes',
        'минуту': 'minutes',
        'минуты': 'minutes',
        'минут': 'minutes',

        's': 'seconds',
        'sec': 'seconds',
        'secs': 'seconds',
        'second': 'seconds',
        'seconds': 'seconds',
        'сек': 'seconds',
        'секунда': 'seconds',
        'секунду': 'seconds',
        'секунды': 'seconds',
        'секунд': 'seconds'
    }

    pat = r'[0-9]+[w|week|weeks|н|нед|неделя|недели|недель|неделю|d|day|days|д|день|дня|дней|h|hour|hours|ч|час|часа|часов|min|mins|minute|minutes|мин|минута|минуту|минуты|минут|s|sec|secs|second|seconds|c|сек|секунда|секунду|секунды|секунд]{1}'
    def timestr_to_dict(tstr):
        #convert 1d2h3m4s to {"d": 1, "h": 2, "m": 3, "s": 4}
        return {conv_dict[p[-1]]: int(p[:-1]) for p in re.findall(pat, str_time)}

    def timestr_to_seconds(tstr):
        return datetime.timedelta(**timestr_to_dict(tstr)).total_seconds()

    def plural(n, arg):
        days = []
        if language == "ru":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['неделя', 'недели', 'недель']
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['день', 'дня', 'дней']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['час', 'часа', 'часов']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']
        elif language == "en":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['week', 'weeks', 'weeks']        
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['day', 'day', 'days']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['hour', 'hour', 'hours']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['minute', 'minute', 'minutes']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['second', 'second', 'seconds']

        if n % 10 == 1 and n % 100 != 11:
            p = 0
        elif 2 <= n % 10 <= 4 and (n % 100 < 10 or n % 100 >= 20):
            p = 1
        else:
            p = 2
        return str(n) + ' ' + days[p]

    counter_in_str = ""
    for i in timestr_to_dict(str_time).items():
        counter_in_str += f"{plural(i[1], i[0])} "

    return int(timestr_to_seconds(str_time)), counter_in_str

#использование:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str_time_to_seconds('1день3часа34min', 'ru'))
```